# encoding to JSON format with php

Tags: php, json

Should be piece of cake, but I don't know how to do this and have been trying to figure it out for too long.

I've written the following .php:

```
<?php 
$data = array( "query" =>  array("code" => "ContentsCode", 
"selection" => array("filter" => "item", "values" => array
("BE0101N1"))), "code" => "Tid", "selection" => array("filter" => 
"item", "values" => array("2010", "2011" )), "response" => array
("format" =>"json")); 

$data_string = json_encode($data);
 echo var_dump($data_string);
?>
```

How it looks:

```
{
    "query": {
        "code": "ContentsCode",
        "selection": {
            "filter": "item",
            "values": [
                "BE0101N1"
            ]
        }
    },
    "code": "Tid",
    "selection": {
        "filter": "item",
        "values": [
            "2010",
            "2011"
        ]
    },
    "response": {
        "format": "json"
    }
}
```

How it SHOULD look:

```
{
    "query": [
        {
            "code": "ContentsCode",
            "selection": {
                "filter": "item",
                "values": [
                    "BE0101N1"
                ]
            }
        },
        "code": "Tid",
        "selection": {
            "filter": "item",
            "values": [
                "2010",
                "2011"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "response": {
        "format": "json"
    }
}
```

The only difference is the "[" after query: and the "]" at the end of line 2.

How do I get the brackets in place? What's missing in my code?

Thanks!

Comment: Just letting you know that you're last piece of "correct" JSON is invalid. You can't have an object without key and *then* have `code` and `selection`.

Comment: You need to put an extra array() around array("code"[...]).

Comment: h2oooooo, The reason my "correct" code looks like it does is because I'm trying to send JSON data to the following API (Scroll down to see the example): http://www.scb.se/en_/About-us/Open-data/API-for-the-Statistical-Database-/

Comment: mistapink, I've tried that, but instead of

 '[' I get ' {"0":'

 and instead of

 ']' i get a '}'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you indent your code it will be obvious

```
$data = array( 
    "query" => array(
        "code" => "ContentsCode", 
        "selection" => array(
            "filter" => "item", 
             "values" => array("BE0101N1")
         )
     ), 
     "code" => "Tid",  
     "selection" => array(
         "filter" => "item", 
         "values" => array("2010", "2011" )
     ),
     "response" => array(
         "format" => "json"
     )
);
```

You need an array around your array containing "code"

```
$data = array( 
    "query" => array(
        array(        
            "code" => "ContentsCode", 
            "selection" => array(
                "filter" => "item", 
                "values" => array("BE0101N1")
            )
        ),
        array(
            "code" => "Tid",  
            "selection" => array(
                "filter" => "item", 
                "values" => array("2010", "2011" )
            ),        
        )
     ), 
     "response" => array(
          "format" => "json"
     )
);
```

Comment: Thanks! did try double array, but had missed the 'array('  before '"code" => "Tid",  '

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to understand the problem when you space it properly. What you have:

```
$data = array(
    "query" => array(
        "code" => "ContentsCode", 
        "selection" => array(
            "filter" => "item",
            "values" => array(
                "BE0101N1"
            )
        )
    ),
    "code" => "Tid",
    "selection" => array(
        "filter" =>  "item",
        "values" => array(
            "2010",
            "2011"
        )
    ),
    "response" => array(
        "format" => "json"
    )
);
```

Here's what you want (comment to help visualize how it translates to JSON):

```
$data = array(
#   query: [
    "query" => array(
#       {
        array(
            "code" => "ContentsCode",
            "selection" => array(
                "filter" => "item",
                "values" => array(
                    "BE0101N1"
                )
            )
#       },
        ),
#       {
        array(
            "code" => "Tid",
            "selection" => array(
                "filter" => "item",
                "values" => array(
                    "2010",
                    "2011"
                )
            )
#       }
        )
#   ],
    ),
#   response: {
    "response" => array(
        "format" => "json"
#   }
    )
);
```

Comment: Thanks! did try double array, but had missed the 'array('  before '"code" => "Tid",

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = array(   
    "query" =>  array(
      array(
        "code" => "ContentsCode", 
        "selection" => array(
          "filter" => "item", 
          "values" => array("BE0101N1")
        )
      ), 
      "code" => "Tid", 
      "selection" => array(
        "filter" => "item", 
        "values" => array("2010", "2011" )
      ) 
    ),

  "response" => array("format" =>"json")
); 

$json_data = json_encode($data);
```

Comment: Thanks Nils. Apparently I missed the 'array('  before '"code" => "Tid",  , thus double array in the beginning wasn't enough to fix the problem.